# How to get the user Email from Firebase with flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, email, dart, firebase-authentication

I am trying to get the email of the user to display it in the account page, This is what I did :

```
getuseremail() async {
    FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    String email;
    final user = _auth.currentUser();
  setState() {() {
    email = user.email;
   }}
 }
```

and Then I display it but It gives me error that it is null.

Comment: What is the exact error? Is it that email is null or is it that user is null?

Comment: email is null .

Comment: The problem will be home you use this method. Since your email variable is declared locally in the method you cannot access it from outside to show it in a Text view. Can you provide your complete widget code, then I can give a more specific answer how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code :

```
  String _email;
  void getUserEmail()  {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((user) {
      setState(() {
        _email = user.email;
      });
    });
  }
```

1, *currentUser* is return *Future*

2, *_email* is need define a field on *State* to *setState*

Answer (score 1):

If the user is currently logged in then you have to do the following:

```
getuseremail() async {
    FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    String email;
    final user = await _auth.currentUser();
  setState() {() {
    email = user.email;
   }}
 }
```

Use `await` since `currentUser()` returns a `Future<FirebaseUser>`, but make sure the user is currently logged in or you won't be able to get the email.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
final user = _auth.currentUser;
```

or use:

```
final user = _auth.getCurrentUser();
```